# How to print something above an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making a messaging thing with sockets.

One problem I am having is that you need input to get the users message

for example

user >> hello

user2 >> hi

you >>

how would you receive a message while having an input and display it above the input.

so if you received a message it would be:

user >> hello

user2 >> hi

user 1 >> nice to meet you

you >>

This is the code i have so far:

```
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 1234

my_username = input('Username: ')

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP,PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)

username = my_username.encode("utf-8")
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")
client_socket.send(username_header + username)


def send_message():
    message = input(f"{my_username} > ")

    if message:
        message = message.encode("utf-8")
        message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode("utf-8")
        client_socket.send(message_header + message)

def receive_message():
    try:    
        while True:
            #receive things
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            if not len(username_header):

                print("connection closed by the server")
                sys.exit()

            username_length = int(username_header.decode("utf-8"))
            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode("utf-8")

            message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8"))
            message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode("utf-8")
            print(f"{username} > {message}")

    except IOError as E:
        if E.errno != errno.EAGAIN and E.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Reading error',str(e))
            sys.exit()

    except Exception as e:
        print('General Error ',str(e))
        sys.exit()


running = True
while running:
    send_message()
    receive_message()
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300245/python-console-application-output-above-input-line