# Python: print message while asking user for input

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I was wondering if someone could help me.
So I'm doing a chat in python with sockets and I'm using threads so that the client can listen and send messages simultaneously.

But I'm having an issue as when the client receives a message it messes up the input (it prints the received message as the user's input).

I was wondering therefore if there were no ways to cancel the input when a message is received, print the received message then ask for an input again

Or if something could be done with the threads ?

If you need here is my thread code:

```
recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target=recieve)
recieve_thread.start()
write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

and here is the input and print message code bit

```
message = input("Me: ")
message = formatMess(nickname, message)
client.send(message.encode('ascii'))
```

```
message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
print(message)
```

Thank you

Comment: You have to create two sockets programs as one for client socket and another for server socket.. You first have to connect all your clients to the server and then start communication between client to client via server..

Comment: Already done that

Comment: So when the client wants to send a message, it send it to the server that then broadcasts it to all the clients connected to it

Comment: My problem is really handling an input and a print, when a message is received I have to print it whilst still allowing user to write

Comment: Than can you just share some more code to let us understand your problem more properly ?

Comment: sure my bad, updating it

Comment: Ideally, have a separate window for input and output, like all GUI messenger-like apps use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71087379/6361014), you can use the following to print messages above the input line.

```
import threading


LOCK = threading.Lock()  # lock to avoid mixing messages while printing


def print_message(message):
    """ print the received message line by line above the input line"""
    with LOCK:
        for line in str.splitlines(message):
            print(
                "\u001B[s"             # Save current cursor position
                "\u001B[A"             # Move cursor up one line
                "\u001B[999D"          # Move cursor to beginning of line
                "\u001B[S"             # Scroll up/pan window down 1 line
                "\u001B[L",            # Insert new line
                 end="")     
            print(line, end="")        # Print message line
            print("\u001B[u", end="")  # Move back to the former cursor position
        print("", end="", flush=True)  # Flush message
```

As an illustration, here is a fake message reception:

```
import threading
import time


def receive():
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        message = "hello \n\t" + str(i)
        i +=1 
        print_message(message=message)
            
            
def write():
    while True:
        x = input('>')


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i was wondering though
are there no neater ways of doing it ? maybe with queues and threads idk ?

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately I do not see other way of doing this.

Comment: @Beni I have refactored the code. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Yeah thank you so much it helped a lot, ill use that thanks again